# How to echo Tags and Categories as plain text

Tags: categories, taxonomy, tags

I am creating custom code to add `schema.org` markups to a page template.
I wanted to echo the tags and categories as plain text to use them in the `keywords` and `about` markup fields.

I can display the tags with a code like this:

`echo '<meta itemprop="keywords" content="'; echo the_tags(); echo'"/>';`

but since the output is an array of link, the Google online markup test tool does not recognize the words. Also, the words have a prefix: `Tags:`.

My question is: is there a way to output the tags and categories of a post as plain text so I can use it inside the Schema markups that I am creating?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's many ways to do it,

You must add parameters to the function to override default value, first parameter must be empty

```
the_tags( '' );

echo '<meta itemprop="keywords" content="'. the_tags( '') .''"/>';
```

There is also `wp_get_post_terms()` function if you want more control,

Create a function in functions.php

```
function wpse_get_tags(){
   global $post;
   $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'post_tag', array("fields" => "all"));
       foreach($term_list as $term_single) {
           $tags .= $term_single->name .', '; // do the job to remove last comma
       }
     return $tags;
 }
```

In your code

```
echo '<meta itemprop="keywords" content="''.wpse_get_tags().''"/>';
```